# Disk space error on ubuntu while trying to install a program (Lead DBS)

Tags: ubuntu, installation, space, tmp

I'm trying to install a program and running into disk error issues. When I run the command

```
./LeadDBSinstaller.install
```

I get this error:

```
/tmp/mwkPH896/bundle.zip:  write error (disk full?).  Continue? (y/n/^C)
```

My df -h looks like this:

> ```
> Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
> udev             16G     0   16G   0% /dev
> tmpfs           3.2G  2.2M  3.2G   1% /run
> /dev/sdb4       137G  130G   12K 100% /
> tmpfs            16G     0   16G   0% /dev/shm
> tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
> tmpfs            16G     0   16G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
> /dev/loop3      3.8M  3.8M     0 100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/123
> /dev/loop2      4.3M  4.3M     0 100% /snap/gnome-calculator/544
> /dev/loop1       45M   45M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1353
> /dev/loop0      1.0M  1.0M     0 100% /snap/gnome-logs/61
> /dev/loop5      3.8M  3.8M     0 100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/127
> /dev/loop4       15M   15M     0 100% /snap/gnome-characters/399
> /dev/loop6       55M   55M     0 100% /snap/core18/1668
> /dev/loop7      1.0M  1.0M     0 100% /snap/gnome-logs/81
> /dev/loop8      157M  157M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/110
> /dev/loop9      4.2M  4.2M     0 100% /snap/gnome-calculator/406
> /dev/loop12      15M   15M     0 100% /snap/gnome-characters/375
> /dev/loop10      92M   92M     0 100% /snap/core/8592
> /dev/loop13     161M  161M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/116
> /dev/loop14      55M   55M     0 100% /snap/core18/1650
> /dev/loop15      45M   45M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1440
> /dev/sda1       256M   34M  223M  14% /boot/efi
> tmpfs           3.2G   16K  3.2G   1% /run/user/121
> tmpfs           3.2G   40K  3.2G   1% /run/user/1000
> /dev/sda5       930G  661G  269G  72% /media/nir/SharedDrive
> /dev/loop16      92M   92M     0 100% /snap/core/8689
> /dev/sdc        2.7T  1.1T  1.5T  44% /media/nir/SharedDrive2
> ```

I'm trying to install from the home/nir/Documents/MATLAB/ directory

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think is because your sdb4 is full and is mount at root (/) i suggest to bind the folders you need to an other drive

Comment: oh thanks for your reply. How do I do that? I apologize, I am an ubuntu-noob

Comment: the command for binding is mount with param bind example : "sudo mount --bind /path/source /path/destination" and edit /etc/fstab to have it at reboot  good luck.